# Get a specific value and count of nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've seen some answers here about this topic but I can't really get what I want. I'm making a menu and I need to assign links. So how can I get a particular node's value? For example how to get the value of the subMenus[0] `<subMenu id="submenu1"><hrefSubMenu>`, which is `http://www.web01.com`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu>
  <link id="0">
    <title>Main Link 01</title> 
    <href>http://www.mainweb01.com</href>
    <subMenus>
      <subMenu id="sublink1">
        <titleSubMenu>SubMenu01</titleSubMenu>
        <hrefSubMenu>http://www.web01.com</hrefSubMenu> 
      </subMenu>
      <subMenu id="sublink2">
        <titleSubMenu>SubMenu02</titleSubMenu>
        <hrefSubMenu>http://www.web02.com</hrefSubMenu>
      </subMenu>
    </subMenus>
  </link>
  <link id="1">
    <title>Main Link 02</title>
    <href>http://www.mainweb02.com</href>
    <subMenus>
      <subMenu id="sublink3">
        <titleSubMenu>SubMenu03</titleSubMenu>
        <hrefSubMenu>http://www.web03.com</hrefSubMenu>
      </subMenu>
      <subMenu id="sublink4">
        <titleSubMenu>SubMenu04</titleSubMenu>
        <hrefSubMenu>http://www.web04.com</hrefSubMenu>
      </subMenu>
      <subMenu id="sublink5">
        <titleSubMenu>SubMenu05</titleSubMenu>
        <hrefSubMenu>http://www.web05.com</hrefSubMenu>
      </subMenu>
    </subMenus>
  </link>
</menu>
```

Using something like this, I can get a particular node's value from the whole title.

```
//if I want to get the first title
var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
alert(name);
//the output will be Main Link 01
```

But I want to get a particular node's value, as I said as an example, the nodeValue from subMenus[0]`<subMenu id"sublink1"><hrefSubMenu>`, which has the value "http://www.web01.com" (I will just adapt any solution in order to find and get whatever node value that I want). But I need that help to know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help that you could give me.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element nodes don't have a node value.

The element `<subMenu id="sublink1">` has a **child** element node `hrefSubMenu`, which in turn has a child text node `http://www.web01.com`. The node value of a text node is the text itself.

So I believe you want:

```js
var href = xmlDoc.getElementById('sublink1') // get subMenu element
    .getElementsByTagName('hrefSubMenu')[0] // get hrefSubMenu child
    .firstChild.nodeValue; // get node value of text node
```

Comment: Hi @Felix Kling thanks for your time, It seems that this does work just on Chrome (It outputs the href), but IE doesn't support this method and FF and Opera crashed. But it's quite what I want. is there a cross browsing solution, a workaround or a frame solution (jquery) to do exactly something like this?. Thank you very much, this is a great start. Greetings.

Comment: I've change a little bit the code and it does work like a charm.

Comment: var href = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('subMenu')[0].getElementsByTagName('hrefSubMenu')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

Comment: Mmh, `getElementById` should have worked I guess (I thought it's a bit simpler), but I'm glad you figured it out :)